# one god for different rubies with rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm, god

I have two apps on my machine.

Each app (server) has it's own gemset and works on a different ruby version.

I will manage those apps with god which is installed in it's own gemset.

My god config file `config.god` looks like this:

```
God.watch do |w|
  current_path = "/home/vagrant/server-1"
  w.name = "server 1"
  w.start = "ruby #{current_path}/simple-server.rb"
  w.keepalive
end

God.watch do |w|
  current_path = "/home/vagrant/server-2"
  w.name = "server 2"
  w.start = "ruby #{current_path}/simple-server.rb"
  w.keepalive
end
```

My servers are simply writing the ruby version to a file (`/home/vagrant/server-2/simple-server.rb`):

```
require "date"

loop do
  # simple console output
  puts "Hello on #{RUBY_VERSION}, #{RUBY_PATCHLEVEL}, #{RUBY_PLATFORM}, #{RUBY_RELEASE_DATE}"

  # Specify the name of the log file
  log_file = File.join File.expand_path( File.dirname(__FILE__) ), "testfile.txt"

    # Write the log into the file
    File.open( log_file, 'a') do |f|
        date = DateTime.now
        date = date.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

        f.puts "#{date} on #{RUBY_VERSION}, #{RUBY_PATCHLEVEL}, #{RUBY_PLATFORM}, #{RUBY_RELEASE_DATE}"
    end

  sleep 2
end
```

I run god with `god -c config.god`.

The problem is that my apps are not running with the ruby versions which is specified in the .rvmrc.

I have also tried:

- `~/.rvm/bin/wrapped_god -d config.god -D`
- `rvmsudo ~/.rvm/bin/wrapped_god -d config.god -D`
- `rvmsudo god -d config.god -D`

Is there a solution for this case?

**EDIT** 2012.08.27:

I have changed my god config as follows:

```
w.start="~/.rvm/bin/rvm in #{current_path} do ruby simple-server.rb"
```

And it worked.

Comment: You mean `god` doesn't use needed ruby version even if wrapped with rvm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
start="~/.rvm/bin/rvm in #{current_path} do ruby simple-server.rb"
```

Comment: No, it's not working. How does this supposed to work? When I call it from the command line I get `Unrecognized command line argument: 'in' ( see: 'rvm usage' )`

Comment: this means you are using old rvm, update it: `rvm get stable` and it should work.

Comment: @czerasz `curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` - and make sure new console is open .. also are you updating the same rvm as you use ?